# How should I deal with `*_id` columns when reading a CSV with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a couple of columns with the suffix `_id` in a CSV file. Most of them are integers, but sometimes they have no value (NaN - empty in the CSV file). For example, some names could be:

- user_id
- device_id
- company_id
- country_id
- ...

When I use `pd.read_csv` it recognizes some of them as int64 and some as float64. I'm not sure, but I think the "correct" type would be `object` for those identifiers.

I know that `read_csv` has the `dtype` attribute. So what I could do is:

```
dtypes = {'user_id': str,
          'device_id': str,
          'company_id': str,
          'country_id': str}
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=dtypes)
```

The disadvantage of this is that I have to specify all of the columns. Is there a way to apply this to all "*_id" columns? Does it make a difference if I use `df['user_id'].astype(object)` afterwards, when pandas already "recognized" int64 or float64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preprocessing for extract columns with `_id`, convert it to dict and then use `red_csv`:

```
path_csv = 'file.csv'
with open(path_csv) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    #get header to list
    header = [x.strip() for x in lines[0].split(',') if '_id' in x]

print (header)
['user_id', 'device_id', 'company_id', 'country_id']

d = dict.fromkeys(header, 'str')
print (d)
{'user_id': 'str', 'device_id': 'str', 'company_id': 'str', 'country_id': 'str'}

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=d)
print (df)
  user_id device_id company_id country_id  country
0       1         2          3          4        5

print (df.dtypes)
user_id       object
device_id     object
company_id    object
country_id    object
country        int64
dtype: object
```

> Does it make a difference if I use df['user_id'].astype(object) afterwards, when pandas already "recognized" int64 or float64?

It depends of data, but if some `NaN`s with integer it should convert `int` to `float`. Also precision of `float` should be changed.